# Timer.start() doesn't seem to work in As3

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement, timer, keyboard

I am trying to measure how long the up/down key are being pressed at a time. Functions timerDownHandler and timerUpHandler are supposed to take care of starting and reseting the timers. There are trace statements in both functions that indicate when you start to hold the key and when you let go. This works fine proving that the if statements are working properly. However, when I try to trace the difference in time, I always get zero. This seems to be linked with the timer not starting at all. Thanks in advance.

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

public class Player extends MovieClip {

    private var up:Boolean = false; 
    private var down:Boolean = false;
    private var accelTimer:Timer; 
    private var accelTimerStart:Boolean = false;
    private var accelTimeDif:int = 0;
    private var deccelTimer:Timer;
    private var deccelTimerStart:Boolean = false;
    private var deccelTimeDif:int = 0;
    private var gravity:int = 5;
    private var acceleration:int = 3;
    private var power:int = 5;

    public function Player() {

        init();
    }

    private function init() {

        accelTimer = new Timer(10);
        deccelTimer = new Timer(10); 
        parent.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
        parent.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
    }

    public function update() {

        timerUpHandler();
        timerDownHandler();
        movementHandler();
        deccelTimeDif == deccelTimer.currentCount;
        accelTimeDif == accelTimer.currentCount;

        trace(deccelTimeDif);
    }

    private function movementHandler():void {

        if (up == true) {

            y = y - 10 * Math.pow(accelTimeDif, 2);
        }

        if (down == true) {

            y = y + 10 * Math.pow(deccelTimeDif, 2);
        }
    }

    private function keyDownHandler(k:KeyboardEvent) {

        if (k.keyCode == 38) {

            up = true;
        }

        else if (k.keyCode == 40) {

            down = true;
        }
    }

    private function keyUpHandler(k:KeyboardEvent) {

        if (k.keyCode == 38) {

            up = false;
        }

        else if (k.keyCode == 40) {

            down = false;
        }
    }

    private function timerUpHandler() {

        if (up == true && accelTimerStart == false) {

            trace("Started");
            accelTimer.start();
            accelTimerStart = true;
        }

        else if (up == false && accelTimerStart == true) {

            trace("Stoped");
            accelTimer.stop();
            accelTimer.reset();
            accelTimerStart = false;
        }
    }

    private function timerDownHandler() {

        if (down == true && deccelTimerStart == false) {

            trace("Started");
            deccelTimer.start();
            deccelTimerStart = true;
        }

        else if (down == false && deccelTimerStart == true) {

            trace("Stoped");
            deccelTimer.stop();
            deccelTimer.reset();
            deccelTimerStart = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think a way that you could achieve this and be more efficient would be to on keyDown save the time.

```
var downtime = new Date().getTime()
```

On keyUp compare the two and get the time pressed in ms.

```
var totaltime = new Date().getTime() - downtime
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I have used getTime() once before but what does new Date() do? Thanks.

Comment: The docs say "Returns the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970, universal time, for a Date object. Use this method to represent a specific instant in time when comparing two or more Date objects."

Answer (score 0):

You don't call `update()` from anywhere. Once you start making calls to there, your time difference vars will show something. But, you have to know that in AS3 timers never fire faster than once per frame, so your timers should either be slower than framerate, or you should replace them with an enter frame event listener.

To make `update()` called, use this in your constructor:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
```

And declare the function as you do with any other event listener.

```
function update(e:Event):void {...}
```

Comment: This is only one of my classes which takes care of the player. I have an enter frame loop in my document class that calls the update function within the player once a frame. I do this so that if for instance I wanted to add a pause button, I could control all objects updating from one central position. If the update function wasn't being called, very little would happen as it would only run once. I should have added that in the description. Thank you for your help anyways.